# Controlling x-axis ticks on time series chart with chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm creating a time series chart using Chart.js 4.  Currently, it looks likes this:
[image]
but I only want the x-axis to be labeled every 15 seconds.  So in this example, there would be 3 ticks, at 12:38:30, 12:38:45 and 12:39.
I've tried using stepSize and count, but neither seems to work.

This is my config

```
const config = {
    type: "line",
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            label: "20070480",
            borderColor: "#36A2EB",
            backgroundColor: "#9BD0F5",
            data: [
                [1681792679186, 1096],
                [1681792680186, 1147],
                [1681792681187, 1056],
                [1681792682187, 1100],
                [1681792683188, 1104],
                [1681792684188, 1158],
                [1681792685188, "1124.6319921491659"],
                [1681792686189, "1111.2244897959183"],
                [1681792687189, 1055.937193326791],
                [1681792688189, 1126.530612244898],
                [1681792689190, 1083.415112855741],
                [1681792690190, 1160],
                [1681792691190, "1068.3673469387754"],
                [1681792692191, "1094.2100098135427"],
                [1681792693191, 1159],
                [1681792694191, 1092],
                [1681792695192, 1115],
                [1681792696192, 1083],
                [1681792697192, 1146],
                [1681792698193, 1105],
                [1681792699193, 1085],
                [1681792700193, 1133],
                [1681792701194, 1101],
                [1681792702194, 1107],
                [1681792703195, 1074],
                [1681792704195, 1094],
                [1681792705195, 1126],
                [1681792706196, 1101],
                [1681792707196, 1065],
                [1681792708196, 1108],
                [1681792709197, 1125],
                [1681792710197, 1059],
                [1681792711198, 1186],
                [1681792712198, 1087],
                [1681792713198, 1117],
                [1681792714199, 1062],
                [1681792715199, 1118],
                [1681792716199, 1172],
                [1681792717200, 1148],
                [1681792718200, 1106],
                [1681792719201, 1061],
                [1681792720201, 1139],
                [1681792721201, 1114],
                [1681792722202, 1117],
                [1681792723202, 1123],
                [1681792724202, 1119],
                [1681792725203, 1119],
                [1681792726203, 1175],
                [1681792727204, 1089],
                [1681792728204, 1132],
                [1681792729204, "1130.5201177625124"],
                [1681792730205, "1161.2244897959183"],
                [1681792731205, 1085],
                [1681792732205, "1133.4641805691856"],
                [1681792733206, 1139],
                [1681792734206, 1147],
                [1681792735207, 1109],
                [1681792736207, "1152.0408163265306"],
                [1681792737207, "1087.3405299313054"],
                [1681792738208, 1145],
                [1681792739208, 1163],
                [1681792740208, 1061],
                [1681792741209, "1151.0204081632653"],
                [1681792742209, "1076.5456329735036"],
                [1681792743209, 1048],
                [1681792744210, 1117],
                [1681792745210, 1105],
                [1681792746210, 1103],
                [1681792747211, 1122],
                [1681792748211, 1105],
                [1681792749212, 1095],
                [1681792750212, 1141],
                [1681792751212, 1138],
                [1681792752212, 1160],
                [1681792753213, 1106],
                [1681792754213, 1077],
                [1681792755213, 1087],
                [1681792756214, 1138],
                [1681792757214, 1103],
                [1681792758215, 1114],
                [1681792759215, 1130],
                [1681792760215, 1128],
                [1681792761216, 1100],
                [1681792762216, 1068],
                [1681792763216, 1143],
                [1681792764217, 1142],
                [1681792765217, 1118],
                [1681792766218, 1089],
                [1681792767218, 1122],
                [1681792768218, 1122],
                [1681792769218, 1080],
                [1681792770219, 1182],
                [1681792771219, 1162],
                [1681792772220, 1100],
                [1681792773220, 1181],
                [1681792774220, 1103],
                [1681792775221, 1116],
                [1681792776221, 1095],
                [1681792777221, "1047.0588235294117"],
                [1681792778222, "1166.4964249233913"],
                [1681792779222, "1087.2549019607843"],
                [1681792780223, 1125],
                [1681792781223, 1060],
                [1681792782223, 1111],
                [1681792783224, 1057],
                [1681792784224, 1074],
                [1681792785224, "1141.9816138917263"],
                [1681792786225, 1104],
                [1681792787225, "1112.7450980392157"],
                [1681792788226, 1148],
                [1681792789226, 1146],
                [1681792790226, 1098],
                [1681792791227, 1164],
                [1681792792227, 1120],
                [1681792793227, 1144],
                [1681792794228, 1133],
                [1681792795228, 1163],
                [1681792796229, 1101],
                [1681792797229, 1108],
                [1681792798229, 1105]
            ]
        }]
    },

    options: {
        animation: false,
        scales: {
            x: {
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: "Time (UTC)",
                    font: {
                        size: 30,
                        weight: "bold"
                    }
                },
                type: "time",
                ticks: {
                    font: {
                        size: 20,
                        weight: "bold"
                    },
                    minRotation: 45,
                    count: 3,
                  //  stepSize: 15000,
                   // autoSkip: false
                },
                min: 1681792710000,
                max: 1681792740000
            },
            y: {
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: "Count Rate",
                    font: {
                        size: 30,
                        weight: "bold"
                    }
                },
                ticks: {
                    font: {
                        size: 15
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

P.S. Haven't had any luck creating a Codepen or JsFiddle using Chart.js 4.x, but you can use this playground, https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/line/line.html and paste my config into there

Comment: TLDR - use `stepSize: 15`; time axes use the concept of unit, that can be specified by the user as `time.unit`, see [the docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#time-units). If not specified, the unit is computed from the data; in your case it's "second", but it's better to set it explicitly if you're using it - and you are, since the `stepSize` is computed in `units` not milliseconds. See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ocwLm6jf/).

Comment: Thanks.  This works.  Please enter it as an answer.  I had seen the doc you pointed out and I confess I still don't fully understand it.  Why is the unit 'seconds', when they are clearly milliseconds.   And I don't fully understand the formatting where you give it different formats for different units.  How does the unit change?

Comment: The unit is relevant in the way the tick marks are rounded. In that fiddle I put under comments the variant `unit: "millisecond"`; you may use that and then you have to set `stepSize: 15000` to get the three ticks, but the text will be `7:38:00.000`. So, that's the solution  the authors of `chart.js` found to give a consistent approach to all things time-related, by replacing the hard js time unit of ms with the more abstract `unit` that gives more control to the user. *Note*; don't experiment with `unit: "minute"` and `stepSize: 0.25` - it gets into a nasty infinite loop :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR - use `stepSize: 15`; time axes use the concept of `unit`, that can be specified by the user as `options.time.unit`, see [the docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#time-units). If not specified, the unit is computed from the data; in your case it's "second", but it's better to set it explicitly if you're using it - and you are, since the `stepSize` is computed in `units` not milliseconds.

```js
const config = {
  type: "line",
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      label: "20070480",
      borderColor: "#36A2EB",
      backgroundColor: "#9BD0F5",
      data: [
        [1681792679186, 1096],
        [1681792680186, 1147],
        [1681792681187, 1056],
        [1681792682187, 1100],
        [1681792683188, 1104],
        [1681792684188, 1158],
        [1681792685188, "1124.6319921491659"],
        [1681792686189, "1111.2244897959183"],
        [1681792687189, 1055.937193326791],
        [1681792688189, 1126.530612244898],
        [1681792689190, 1083.415112855741],
        [1681792690190, 1160],
        [1681792691190, "1068.3673469387754"],
        [1681792692191, "1094.2100098135427"],
        [1681792693191, 1159],
        [1681792694191, 1092],
        [1681792695192, 1115],
        [1681792696192, 1083],
        [1681792697192, 1146],
        [1681792698193, 1105],
        [1681792699193, 1085],
        [1681792700193, 1133],
        [1681792701194, 1101],
        [1681792702194, 1107],
        [1681792703195, 1074],
        [1681792704195, 1094],
        [1681792705195, 1126],
        [1681792706196, 1101],
        [1681792707196, 1065],
        [1681792708196, 1108],
        [1681792709197, 1125],
        [1681792710197, 1059],
        [1681792711198, 1186],
        [1681792712198, 1087],
        [1681792713198, 1117],
        [1681792714199, 1062],
        [1681792715199, 1118],
        [1681792716199, 1172],
        [1681792717200, 1148],
        [1681792718200, 1106],
        [1681792719201, 1061],
        [1681792720201, 1139],
        [1681792721201, 1114],
        [1681792722202, 1117],
        [1681792723202, 1123],
        [1681792724202, 1119],
        [1681792725203, 1119],
        [1681792726203, 1175],
        [1681792727204, 1089],
        [1681792728204, 1132],
        [1681792729204, "1130.5201177625124"],
        [1681792730205, "1161.2244897959183"],
        [1681792731205, 1085],
        [1681792732205, "1133.4641805691856"],
        [1681792733206, 1139],
        [1681792734206, 1147],
        [1681792735207, 1109],
        [1681792736207, "1152.0408163265306"],
        [1681792737207, "1087.3405299313054"],
        [1681792738208, 1145],
        [1681792739208, 1163],
        [1681792740208, 1061],
        [1681792741209, "1151.0204081632653"],
        [1681792742209, "1076.5456329735036"],
        [1681792743209, 1048],
        [1681792744210, 1117],
        [1681792745210, 1105],
        [1681792746210, 1103],
        [1681792747211, 1122],
        [1681792748211, 1105],
        [1681792749212, 1095],
        [1681792750212, 1141],
        [1681792751212, 1138],
        [1681792752212, 1160],
        [1681792753213, 1106],
        [1681792754213, 1077],
        [1681792755213, 1087],
        [1681792756214, 1138],
        [1681792757214, 1103],
        [1681792758215, 1114],
        [1681792759215, 1130],
        [1681792760215, 1128],
        [1681792761216, 1100],
        [1681792762216, 1068],
        [1681792763216, 1143],
        [1681792764217, 1142],
        [1681792765217, 1118],
        [1681792766218, 1089],
        [1681792767218, 1122],
        [1681792768218, 1122],
        [1681792769218, 1080],
        [1681792770219, 1182],
        [1681792771219, 1162],
        [1681792772220, 1100],
        [1681792773220, 1181],
        [1681792774220, 1103],
        [1681792775221, 1116],
        [1681792776221, 1095],
        [1681792777221, "1047.0588235294117"],
        [1681792778222, "1166.4964249233913"],
        [1681792779222, "1087.2549019607843"],
        [1681792780223, 1125],
        [1681792781223, 1060],
        [1681792782223, 1111],
        [1681792783224, 1057],
        [1681792784224, 1074],
        [1681792785224, "1141.9816138917263"],
        [1681792786225, 1104],
        [1681792787225, "1112.7450980392157"],
        [1681792788226, 1148],
        [1681792789226, 1146],
        [1681792790226, 1098],
        [1681792791227, 1164],
        [1681792792227, 1120],
        [1681792793227, 1144],
        [1681792794228, 1133],
        [1681792795228, 1163],
        [1681792796229, 1101],
        [1681792797229, 1108],
        [1681792798229, 1105]
      ]
    }]
  },

  options: {
    animation: false,
    scales: {
      x: {
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: "Time (UTC)",
          font: {
            //size: 30,
            weight: "bold"
          }
        },
        type: "time",
        time: {
          //unit: "millisecond", // try this with stepsize 15000
          unit: "second" // that's the computed unit for this data
        },
        //beforeBuildTicks: function(ax){
        //   console.log(ax._unit);
        //},
        ticks: {
          font: {
            //size: 20,
            weight: "bold"
          },

          minRotation: 45,
          //count: 3,
          stepSize: 15,
          // autoSkip: false
        },
        min: 1681792710000,
        max: 1681792740000
      },
      y: {
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: "Count Rate",
          font: {
            //size: 30,
            weight: "bold"
          }
        },
        ticks: {
          font: {
           // size: 15
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

new Chart(document.querySelector('#myChart'), config);
```

```html
<div class="chart-container" style="width: 90vw">
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.3.0/chart.umd.min.js" integrity="sha512-TJ7U6JRJx5IpyvvO9atNnBzwJIoZDaQnQhb0Wmw32Rj5BQHAmJG16WzaJbDns2Wk5VG6gMt4MytZApZG47rCdg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-date-fns@3.0.0/dist/chartjs-adapter-date-fns.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

The same in [this fiddle](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#time-units)

Now, the unit is relevant in the way the tick marks are rounded. In the code above I put under comments the variant `unit: "millisecond"`; you may use that and then you have to set `stepSize: 15000` to get the three ticks, but then the text will be `7:38:30.000`.

So, I guess that's the solution the authors of `chart.js` found to give a consistent approach to all things time-related, by replacing the hard javascript time unit of 1ms, with the more abstract unit that gives more control to the user. *Note*: don't experiment with `unit: "minute"` and `stepSize: 0.25` - it gets into a nasty infinite loop :)

The variant where you set different tick formats for different units can be seen as "preventive": don't explicitly set the `unit`, let the code choose the optimal one from the data, and if it happens to be `second` use this format, and if it happens to be `minute`, use the other one, etc. It also makes sense with dynamic data, that comes from an external source, so the programmer might not know a priori what the appropriate unit will be.